# Beamer frame title manually change vertical and horizontal position

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am trying to change the vertical and horizontal positions of my frame titles and subtitles. So far I am using

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
```

but I would like more control. Is it possible to define a shift to the right using mm or pixels in place of the `center` argument?

Cheers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default]` is defined in `beamerouterthemedefault.sty`. If you take the definition from there, you can redefine it according to your needs. For example add a shift with `\hspace*{1cm}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
    \@tempdima=\textwidth%
    \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
    \hspace*{1cm} %%%%%%%%%%%%% For example insert shift to right
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,center,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
        \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
        \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@ftecenter\endcsname\fi%
        \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
        {%
            \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
            \else%
            {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
            \fi
        }%
        \vskip-1ex%
        \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{te}
        abc
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this solution it works great for the frame title, how can I also readjust the frame subtitle position if the frame has one?

Comment: @QuantumPenguin As `frametitle` and `framesubtitle` are in the same `beamercolorbox` they both move if you add the `\hspace` outside from the box. Can you show an example of what additional adjustments you want?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, what I meant is, is it possible to left justify the the Frame title Frame Subtitles with each-other?

Comment: @QuantumPenguin Maybe put both inside a `minipage` or similar. But you might have to think about the width of it.